# MySQL multiplication returning wrong result

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have two tables related by a foreign key.
employee table is as follows:

```
+----+------------+-----------+---------------+
| id | first_name | last_name | billable_rate |
+----+------------+-----------+---------------+
|  1 | James      | Maxston   |           300 |
|  2 | Sean       | Scott     |           500 |
+----+------------+-----------+---------------+
```

timesheet table is as follows:

```
+----+----------+------------+------------+----------+-------------+
| id | project  | date       | start_time | end_time | employee_id |
+----+----------+------------+------------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | AIT      | 2020-07-20 | 09:00:00   | 12:00:00 |           1 |
|  2 | Axiiscom | 2020-06-20 | 15:00:00   | 17:00:00 |           1 |
|  3 | AIT      | 2020-07-20 | 13:00:00   | 18:00:00 |           1 |
|  4 | AIT      | 2020-07-01 | 11:00:00   | 14:00:00 |           2 |
|  5 | AIT      | 2020-06-21 | 11:00:00   | 12:00:00 |           2 |
+----+----------+------------+------------+----------+-------------+
```

Running the query below:

```
SELECT 
    project, employee_id, @hours_worked := SUM(timestampdiff(HOUR, start_time, end_time)) AS number_of_hours, 
    @hourly_rate :=my_db.employee.billable_rate AS unit_price,
    @hours_worked * @hourly_rate AS cost
FROM 
    my_db.timesheet
INNER JOIN 
    my_db.employee ON my_db.employee.id = my_db.timesheet.employee_id
WHERE 
    project = "AIT"
GROUP BY 
    employee_id;
```

yields the following result:

```
+---------+-------------+-----------------+------------+-------------------------------------+
| project | employee_id | number_of_hours | unit_price | cost                                |
+---------+-------------+-----------------+------------+-------------------------------------+
| AIT     |           1 |               8 |        300 | 1200.000000000000000000000000000000 |
| AIT     |           2 |               4 |        500 | 2000.000000000000000000000000000000 |
+---------+-------------+-----------------+------------+-------------------------------------+
```

when instead I expected it would yield this result:

```
+---------+-------------+-----------------+------------+-------------------------------------+
| project | employee_id | number_of_hours | unit_price | cost                                |
+---------+-------------+-----------------+------------+-------------------------------------+
| AIT     |           1 |               8 |        300 | 2400.000000000000000000000000000000 |
| AIT     |           2 |               4 |        500 | 2000.000000000000000000000000000000 |
+---------+-------------+-----------------+------------+-------------------------------------+
```

Where am I going wrong in my query?

Comment: Please learn to use a proper `GROUP BY`.  The query shouldn't have executed.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using variables a simple aggregation can do the processing you need. For example, you can do:

```
select
  t.project,
  t.employee_id,
  sum(timestampdiff(HOUR, t.start_time, t.end_time)) as number_of_hours,
  max(e.billable_rate) as unit_price,
  sum(timestampdiff(HOUR, t.start_time, t.end_time)) 
    * max(e.billable_rate) as cost
from my_db.timesheet t
join my_db.employee e on e.id = t.employee_id
where t.project = 'AIT'
group by t.project, t.employee_id
```

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL you don't have much control over when `@variable` values are updated while processing queries.  So avoid them for the purpose you're using. They lead to confusion.

You can still make your business logic (in your case the computation of `cost`) reasonably easy to read.

Try using a nested query instead: something like this.

```
SELECT project, employee_id, number_of_hours, unit_price, 
       unit_price * number_of_hours AS cost
  FROM (
          SELECT my_db.timesheet.project,
                 my_db.timesheet.employee_id,
                 SUM(timestampdiff(HOUR, start_time, end_time)) AS number_of_hours, 
                 my_db.employee.billable_rate AS unit_price
            FROM my_db.timesheet
           INNER JOIN my_db.employee 
                       ON my_db.employee.id = my_db.timesheet.employee_id
           GROUP BY my_db.timesheet.project, 
                    my_db.timesheeet.employee_id,
                    my_db.employee.billable_rate
       ) summary
 WHERE project = 'AIT'
 ORDER BY employee_id
```

MySQL's query planner does a reasonably good job of handing this kind of nested query, so you don't have to worry too much about performance.

If you want you can define the inner query as a view. Then your outer query is really easy to read.

```
SELECT project, employee_id, number_of_hours, unit_price, 
       unit_price * number_of_hours AS cost
  FROM my_db.project_summary
 WHERE project = 'AIT'
 ORDER BY employee_id
```

To create the view, you do

```
   CREATE VIEW my_db.project_summary AS
          SELECT my_db.timesheet.project,
                 my_db.timesheet.employee_id,
                 SUM(timestampdiff(HOUR, start_time, end_time)) AS number_of_hours, 
                 my_db.employee.billable_rate AS unit_price
            FROM my_db.timesheet
           INNER JOIN my_db.employee 
                       ON my_db.employee.id = my_db.timesheet.employee_id
           GROUP BY my_db.timesheet.project, 
                    my_db.timesheeet.employee_id,
                    my_db.employee.billable_rate
```

Easy to read is good.